# Workstations are disconnected from server after 10 hours

Tags: windows-server-2012

We recently had some electrical work done and the domain server went off unintentionally rather than being switched off. Since then, the workstations can only connect to the server for 10 hours before having to log out of Windows and back in again, they just suddenly lose their connection to the server.

Has something got corrupted, or is there something which expires after 10 hours (like a security token or something), if so what can I look for to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this in the future, I did eventually remedy it.

The server had two network cards, one on 192.168.0.1 and one on 192.168.0.2 however the 0.2 card didn't have a network cable plugged into it, however due to some kind of bridging it was resolving back to the server correctly.

I disabled the 0.2 network card and changed the DNS server to work off 0.1 instead of 0.2, that seemed to fix the problem.